# How to get user data when I provide the uid or username - Services

Tags: services

I am using postman.
I want to provide the *username* or *uid* and fetch the user's information.
What should be the URL.

Comment: Can you elaborate more on the question? Plus mention what have you actually tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

URL to fetch the user information by providing uid as follows.

```
http://[yourdomain]/[endpoint]/user/[uid]
```

Example: `http://www.example.com/rest/user/2` will fetch user information, having user id 2.

You can get the user data by providing username, you can use pass name (username) as a parameter to the service URL like follows

```
http://example.com/<endpoint path>/user?parameters[name]=krishna
```

If you have enabled session authentication you might have to pass X-CSRF-Token in headers.
For session authentication you can find my [answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/133580/25879) here

Comment: oh where to mark it as accepted? and i tried it worked:)

Comment: please tell, instead of uid now, i want to provide username or a field for example roll no. and want to fetch the user information.

Comment: ok. is there a way with hooks ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32783/discussion-between-tulika-sharma-and-krishna-mohan).